# Oracle multiple table Joining

Tags: oracle11g

[image: This is Student Table]

[image: This is Class Table]

[image: This is Teachet Table]

[image: This is pivot Table of Teacher, Student and Class table]

I want to know how we can List the name of students and teachers according to classes?

```
Select
TC.Class_ID,
S.Sudent_Name,
T.Teacher_Name,
C.Class_Type
From Class C
INNER JOIN Teach TC on C.Class_ID=TC.Class_ID
INNER JOIN Student S on TC.Student_ID=S.Student_ID
INNER JOIN Teacher T on TC.Teacher_ID=T.Teacher_ID
Group BY TC.Class_ID
ORDER BY TC.Class_ID;
```

This is my code which doesnot work.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184691/364543) is some advice on how to better ask a question regarding SQL. In general, you want to make it easy for folks to copy & paste data into whatever tool they're using to reproduce a problem. Links to pictures don't make it easy. Additionally, if you have tried something, then you should paste your code in the body of your question along with what you got and what you expect. You should also know that if you don't at least try something, then you are less likely to get help. I say all of this to be helpful. I don't want you to be discouraged.

Comment: select
  Student_Name
from
  Student s
join 
  Teach tc on tc.teach_id = s.teach_id
join
  (select Teacher_Name from Teacher t
  join Teach tc on tc.teach_id=t.teach_id)
  join
  Class c on c.class_id=tc.class_id
group by 
  c.class_id


Sir this is my solution which did not work.
can you please correct it .
I will be so much thankful to you

Comment: Please (a) instead of pictures, put the actual text of the data for someone to more easily copy into their own database so they can test your SQL statement (b) add the text of the output of your query (c) add the text of what you want the output to be.  This is general advice. It's possible that someone might be able to answer the question without the "requirements" that you'll find in "how to ask a good question". But this site is more than that. It's not only supposed to be valuable to you in this instance but also valuable to someone who comes along later asking the same question.